# AngularJS directive for jQuery chosen plugin not working for asynchronously loaded data

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-chosen

I am trying to set up a directive in my AngularJS app for the [jQuery chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), however, the plugin is not updating to show the list of items I load in using AJAX / $http.

A demo of my problem can be [seen on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dAl5axBvK2N3WDgALZfB?p=preview).

Here is the relevant code:

HTML:

```
<select
    style="width: 100%;"
    ng-chosen
    multiple
    ng-model="selectedItem"
    ng-options="item.name for item in items">
</select>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.selectedItems = {};
  $scope.items = undefined;

  $http.get('items.json').then(function(response) {
    $scope.items = response.data;
  }, function() {
    // Error ...
  });
})

.directive("ngChosen", function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {

            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue) {
                // Trigger chosen update
                $(elem).trigger("chosen:updated");
            });

            // Init chosen
            $(elem).chosen();
        }
    };
});
```

How can I get this working so the `chosen` element shows my list of `items`?

Comment: You might want to check out https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen

Comment: I've come across that, but I want to implement something simple like what I have on my own.

Comment: I tried the directive you linked to - but I couldn't even get that working with my situation.